# RF output power too high because of PSU cable

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, rf, emc, emissions

We have a situation where an integrated 868-920MHz RF chip is programmed to output the chip maximum of 14 dBm power. From professional chamber/measurement equipment 16 dBm is measured in the carrier band.

From measuring the setup in different positions, it seems the extra power stems from the incoming wall charger cable. The charger is 5V/3A fully approved by CE/FCC.

The antenna is a somewhat isotropic PIFA. From seperate measurements the extra power does not seem to come from directivity of the antenna.

I can understand the small RSE power magnitudes that we normally measure, but how do we amplify the actual carrier power by this much?

Comment: 2dB more power is about 50% more power (3dB is 2:1). What is the measured value of the +5v?

Comment: It is +5 Volt, but I am do not think the oscilloscope can handle voltages around the GHz range. Do you think we have carrier frequency through the cable?

Comment: Do you have any filtering where the DC power enters your board, such as ferrite beads and decoupling capacitors? If not, then yes, the cable could be radiating significant power.

Comment: There is a big ferrite bead on the PSU cable itself close to the connection receptacle of the product. From here the voltage is stepped down 2 consecutive times through LDO's with ceramics on all sides. PSU->ferrite->10uF->LDO->Many MLCC (down to 47pF)->LDO-> Many MLCC (down to 100n as per app-note)->RF.

Comment: Link the datasheet for the RF SoC please.

Comment: It is a TI CC1312 which is limited at 14dBm output power.